# Finding current and voltage in a circuit

Tags: current, voltage

Assuming that my diode is ideal, how to find $I$, $V$ in each figure?

[image]

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Oh yes am sorry am new to this site

Comment: There's gotta be some examples in your textbook which can be adapted to these resistor configurations!

Comment: This looks like a homework question.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) Assume the diode is off. Then the voltage at the anode of the diode is

$$6V\cdot\frac{20}{10+20}=4V$$

The voltage at the cathode is \$0V\$. This is a contradiction to the assumption that the diode is off, because according to the voltages it should be on. So the diode is on and can be replaced by a short-circuit. This means that the voltage \$V\$ is just half of \$6V\$ because the two lower resistors in parallel just equal the top \$10k\Omega\$ resistor:

$$V=3\textrm{ Volts}$$

The current \$I\$ is the current through the right \$20k\Omega\$ resistor and according to Ohm's law it is:

$$I=\frac{3V}{20k\Omega}=0.15mA$$

(b) Assume again that the diode is off. The voltage at the anode is \$2.5V\$ and the voltage at the cathode is \$3V\$. This confirms our assumption that the diode is off because its forward voltage is \$-0.5V\$. Consequently,

$$V=-0.5V\textrm{ and }I=0A$$

Comment: I'm sorry, but I rlly kind of far away from this field.How did you calculate V anode?

Comment: @user2949483: You mean the first equation in my answer? If the diode is off, then the same current flows through the top and bottom resistor. This current is by Ohm's law 6V/(10k+20k). The voltage across the 20k resistor is then the current times the resistor value: 6V*20k/(10k+20k). This is equal to the voltage at the anode of the diode.

Comment: I see. Thanx alot!

Answer (score 2):

For diode problems like these, the general procedure is to assume one state or the other for the diode and check for consistency.

(1)  Assume the diode is on (replace with a wire) and solve for the current through.  If the diode current is in the reverse direction, the assumption that the diode is on is wrong.  Solve the circuit with the diode off.

(2) Assume the diode is off (replace with an open circuit) and solve for the voltage across.  If the diode voltage is positive, the assumption is wrong.  Solve the circuit with the diode on.

However, in both of the given circuits, it's easy to see what state the diode is in by inspection.  In the first circuit, the diode must be on and for the second circuit, the diode must be off.

For other circuits, it may not be obvious which is the case and one must choose a state and then check for consistency.